# Dockerfile VOLUME not visibile on host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

In the WordPress Dockerfile, there's a `VOLUME /var/www/html` statement. If I understand correctly, this means that the WordPress files (in /var/www/html) should be mapped to the directory on my host containing the docker-compose.yml BUT this is not happening. Do you know why?

I created my own WordPress Dockerfile that extends the original WordPress Dockerfile where you'll find said `VOLUME /var/www/html` statement on line 44 (https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/b3739870faafe1886544ddda7d2f2a88882eeb31/php7.2/apache/Dockerfile).

I even tried to add the `VOLUME /var/www/html` statement at the bottom of my Dockerfile as you can see in my Dockerfile below. I added it just in case but I don't think anything is going wrong in there.

```
FROM wordpress:4.9.8-php7.2-apache

##########
# XDebug #
##########
# Install
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.1; \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
# Configure
RUN echo "error_reporting = E_ALL" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "display_startup_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "display_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.idekey=\"PHPSTORM\"" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.win.localhost" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
    #RUN echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini ##

###########
# PHPUnit #
###########
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install wget

RUN wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-7.4.phar; \
    chmod +x phpunit-7.4.phar; \
    mv phpunit-7.4.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit

RUN phpunit --version

###################
# PHP Codesniffer #
###################
RUN curl -OL https://squizlabs.github.io/PHP_CodeSniffer/phpcs.phar; \
    mv phpcs.phar /usr/local/bin/phpcs; \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpcs

############
# Composer #
############
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"; \
    php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '93b54496392c062774670ac18b134c3b3a95e5a5e5c8f1a9f115f203b75bf9a129d5daa8ba6a13e2cc8a1da0806388a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"; \
    php composer-setup.php; \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"; \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

##################
# Install Nodejs #
##################
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg2; \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash -; \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

##################
# Install Grunt  #
##################
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli

#####################
# BASH customization#
#####################
RUN echo "alias ll='ls --color=auto -lA'" >> ~/.bashrc

VOLUME /var/www/html
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - ./docker-mysql/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: progonkpa/wordpress:1.0
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     restart: always


volumes:
    db_data:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is being created, it just isn't being created in the execution context where you docker-compose.yml file lives. *I assume you are running the `ls -lah` command and expecting something to be created in the directory where your docker-compose.yml file is. That is why you say, "BUT this is not happening"*

The VOLUME command in the Dockerfile is limited. The host is unknown when you build an image from the Dockerfile. It is not until the `docker run` is executed using your built image that the Docker host is known.

And so, when using the VOLUME command in a Dockerfile and then using `docker run` with that image, the volume is created in a location configured by the Docker installation. To confirm that a volume has indeed been created for your container use this command:

docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' [container_name]

To have better control and specify where you VOLUME is created on your Docker host, you need to use the `-v` option with `docker run` or configure in your docker-compose.yml file, like is being done for your MySQL persistence container.

You can remove `VOLUME /var/www/html` from your Dockerfile, and you should. Because your `FROM` wordpress image creates the VOLUME, as you already know.

Comment: Ok, so it's a two step configuration: 1. define VOLUME in Dockerfile. 2. Do the mapping. Another question popped up after this, if you're still up to it, you can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801577/docker-volume-mapping-sync-files-from-guest-to-host

Comment: Well I think it is one step. Define the volume, either in the Dockerfile, or using docker run -v or in your docker-compose.yml. You choose ONE of the 3 places to express it. I would prefer your docker-compose.yml, since you are using docker-compose