# Docker volume mapping sync files from guest to host

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, volume

I created this basic Dockerfile expecting that `test` would become visible like html/test in host, but it didn't. I think because Docker creates an empty html dir in host and syncs that to guest. I tried with docker run and docker-compose, the results were the same.

The thing is, when I do the same actions with the WordPress image from Dockerhub, I see it creates a directory on host, neatly syncing all files from /var/www/html in guest. So now I wonder how I can create the same behaviour.

Dockerfile simple test:

```
FROM php:7.3.0-apache-stretch

RUN touch /var/www/html/test; \
    echo success > /var/www/html/test

VOLUME /var/www/html
```

docker-compose.yml simple test:

```
version: '3'

services:
  php:
    image: progonkpa/php-vol:1.0
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

The thing is, when I do the same actions with the WordPress image from Dockerhub, I see it creates a directory on host, neatly syncing all files from /var/www/html in guest.

[Dockerfile WordPress](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/b3739870faafe1886544ddda7d2f2a88882eeb31/php7.1/apache/Dockerfile)

docker-compose.yml using WordPress official image (progonkpa/wordpress:1.0 adds XDebug and other trivial files)

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - ./docker-mysql/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: progonkpa/wordpress:1.0
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
       - ./src:/var/www/src
       - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor

volumes:
    db_data:
```

Comment: Do you still have VOLUME /var/www/html in your Docker file when your try your docker run -v or docker-compose simple tests? You should remove from the VOLUME command from your Dockerfile when you use docker run -v or docker-compose.yml to define your volume

Comment: Yes it's there, mirroring the WordPress Dockerfile. I also have ./html:/var/www/html in docker-compose.yml, just like ./wordpress:/var/www/html in WordPress' docker-compose.yml. The only difference is that WordPress project syncs files from container to host while simple test doesn't.